# Remove illegal Charactors in String C

Tags: c, string, format

Hello all I have a small problem with formatting a string in C.

`char buffer[1000];`

I have my buffer which has a readout of `"♀ ‼☻☺ ☻ ]\[MY-TEXT"` // shortened

as you can see it contains illegal charactors so I cant use `sscanf` on it. I need to remove all illegal characters and keep all numbers, letters, and the `-` symbol.

Is this possible?

This is my new code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

int main () 
{ 

    char buffer[1000]="♀ ‼☻☺ ☻ ]\[MY-TEXT";

char buffer2[1000]; 
char *in; 
char *out = buffer2; 

for (in=buffer; *in; in++) 
   if (isalnum((unsigned char)*in) || *in == '-') 
       *out++ = *in; 

printf("Output",buffer2);


 system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `printf("Output",buffer2);` -> `printf("Output:%s",buffer2);`

Answer (score 4):

It's generally easiest to copy the data from the existing string to a new one, just keeping the ones you want:

```
char buffer2[1000];
char *in;
char *out = buffer2;

for (in=buffer; *in; in++)
   if (isalnum((unsigned char)*in) || *in == '-')
       *out++ = *in;
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array, and copy only those chars that you accept into another array, using [`isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalnum) and testing for `-`:

```
char tmpBuffer[1000];
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (isalnum(buffer[i]) || (buffer[i] == '-'))
           tmpBuffer[j++] = buffer[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the function `is_valid()` so that it returns a true value (non-zero) for characters you want, and returns a false value (zero) for characters you don't want.  I made it check that the character is a space, or a printable ASCII.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
is_valid(char ch)
{
    if (' ' <= ch && ch <= '~')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void
copy_only_valid(char *out, unsigned int max_out, char const *in)
{
    if (!out || !max_out || !in)
        return;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (*in == '\0' || max_out == 1)
        {
            // When we reach the terminating NUL byte in the input string,
            // or there is only one char left in out buffer, put a NUL byte
            // and return.
            *out = '\0';
            return;
        }
        if (is_valid(*in))
        {
            *out++ = *in++;
            --max_out;
        }
        else
            ++in;
    }
}

int
main()
{
    char const *bad = "\b\nfoo\003\005bar\f\tbaz";
    char buf[128];

    copy_only_valid(buf, sizeof(buf), bad);
    puts(buf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks these worked great in my example but working with my readfile and handle still no joy is there a way to clip say 10 bytes of the start and 10 bytes of the end of a buffer as this is what is causing an issue for me the header junk from microprocessor.